# Getting null pointer exception on getActivity() when trying to navigate through fragments

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, location

I have implemented map in fragment. I want current location so I have implemented Location listener which returns location. I am calling an api to get all merchants so I get the merchants list. From that list I get the latitude and longitude of merchants.

When I first launch the app and go to SearchMerchant fragment which is in home activity, where map is added. I can see current location and marker on that and if I go back to another fragment and again come to SearchMerchant fragment I get the null pointer exception when I try to check for network connection, in onLocationChanged method.

```
Process: com.kiranacustomerapp, PID: 9934 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.kiranacustomerapp.helper.CommonUtils.isConnectedToInternet(CommonUtils.java:44)                                                                          at com.kiranacustomerapp.Fragments.SearchMerchantFragment.onLocationChanged(SearchMerchantFragment.java:373)
                                                                         at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:297)
```

CommonUtils class:

```
    public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if ( manager != null ) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = manager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if ( info != null ) {
            for(int i=0;i<info.length;i++) {
                if ( info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

SearchMapFragment:

```
public class SearchMerchantFragment extends Fragment implements GetSearchedMerchantsAsyncTask.GetSearchedMerchantsCallBack,OnMapReadyCallback , GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //  getLocation();

        initializeLocationManager();
        requestLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_merchant, container, false);

        setUpUI(view);


        return view;
    }


    public void setUpUI(View view) {

        setUpMapIfNeeded();



    }

    @Override
    public void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Merchants> merchantsArrayList) {

        merchantsList.clear();
        merchantsList.addAll(merchantsArrayList);
        merchantsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

  //get searched merchants
    public void accessMerchants() {
        if (CommonUtils.isConnectedToInternet(getContext())) {
            new GetSearchedMerchantsAsyncTask(getActivity(), SearchMerchantFragment.this).execute(access_token, sessionUserId,String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            showAlert(String.valueOf(R.string.check_network));
        }
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            // getLocation();
        }
    }

    //setup map

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        //   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

        private static final String TAG = "GPS";

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
            try {

                if (mLastLocation != null) {

                    //place marker at current position
                    // mGoogleMap.clear();
                    mLatLang = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());

                    accessMerchants();

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(mLatLang);
                    markerOptions.title(getString(R.string.position));
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                    mMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mLatLang).zoom(14).build();

                    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
                    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
                    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

                    for (Merchants merchants : merchantsList) {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(merchants.getLatitude(), merchants.getLongitude());
                        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)).title(merchants.getKirana_name());
                        Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
                        markers.add(m);
                    }
                }
            } catch (SecurityException e) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };
    private void initializeLocationManager() {

        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    public void requestLocation() {

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {

        }

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {

        }

    }

}
```

I want to get the location once and call the async task to get merchants list. After getting the location I want to stop getting location, now as I am calling async task in onLocationChange method it starts calling async task as soon as the location changes. so it happens frequently.

What's going wrong here? Please help, thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setUpUI(view);` in `onCreateView()` which calls `getLocation()`. In your `getLocation()` you are calling `getActivity()` for getting **LocationManager** instance. The `getActivity()` is returning null because you are calling that in `onCreateView()`.

Problem is you should not call `getContext()` or `getActivity()` in `onCreateView()` because there is no guarantee that the activity is created, so context will be null. This happens only sometime not all the time.

**Note:** You should make a habit not to get the context in `onCreateView()`, get it in `onActivityCreated()`.

**Very simple to fix**:
Move your `getLocation()` call in `onActivityCreated()` which is guaranteed at this situation you get the context and also all the methods or lines which uses context:)

Comment: still getting null pointer exception and on map I cant see location if navigating from fragments.

Answer (score 0):

check

```
CommonUtils.isConnectedToInternet(getActivity())
```

see if **getActivity()** is not returning you null.

move your **getLocation();** method inside **onActivityCreated()** or should be called in onConnect();

Comment: still getting null pointer exception and on map I cant see location if navigating from fragments